# Java - Testing an integer number if it is divisible by 3?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FindNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer number: ");
            int number = scnr.nextInt();

            if (number > 100) {
                System.out.println("End!");
            break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                if (number % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This number is divisible by 3!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("This number is indivisible by 3!");
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find what was wrong with it as if the input was any number that was indivisible by 3, it works.
But for any number that is divisible by 3, it prints (the number inputted) lines of output.

Output:

```
Please enter an integer number: 1
This number is indivisible by 3!
Please enter an integer number: 2
This number is indivisible by 3!
Please enter an integer number: 4
This number is indivisible by 3!
Please enter an integer number: 3
This number is divisible by 3!
This number is divisible by 3!
This number is divisible by 3!
Please enter an integer number:
```

Comment: Well what did you expect it to do? That's what your `for` loop means. Take out the `for` loop and it will only be printed once.

Comment: Number % 3 should be i % 3

Comment: Try to avoid using image to post both codes and results if it is purely text. You may just copy and paste.

Comment: what are you hoping to achieve with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your for loop:

```
        if (number % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("This number is divisible by 3!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This number is indivisible by 3!");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Hey, I got it. Just missing a break took me 2 hours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @QuânLê What do you mean? Your code already uses a `while` loop to keep taking more inputs until one of them is greater than `100`.

Comment: @QuânLê If you want it to keep looping and asking for more inputs, you can remove the break statements in the if/else block, but it will keep looping forever with that while(true) statement.  Consider replacing while(true) with for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) to limit to 4 iterations